# How can we check if an image exists inside a button in python's kivy library?

Tags: python, image, button, kivy, widget

So the problem I am having is that I have placed an image inside my button object in my .kv file and I want to check that if an image exists inside the button. Now the problem here is that they both are widgets (one inside the other) so my instance method isn't working. Below is my code.

```
GridLayout:
    id: chess_board
    cols: 8
    rows: 8
    padding: ("60dp", "60dp", "60dp", "60dp")
    orientation: 'tb-lr'
    
    Button:
        id: button_1
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: app.moves(self)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_1
            source: 'imgs/WhiteCastle.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

So now I want to check if an AsyncImage exists in a button because in some other buttons that I have created it does not exist. Can someone plzzz help. Below is my .py file.

```
def moves(self, instance):
    all_ids = instance.parent.parent.ids.items()
    id = self.get_id(instance)
    print(id)

def get_id(self, instance):
    for id, widget in instance.parent.parent.ids.items():
        if widget.__self__ == instance:
            return id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `moves()` method a bit, like this:

```
def moves(self, instance, root):
    if 'white_1' in root.ids:
        asyncImage = root.ids.white_1
        if asyncImage in instance.children:
            print('Button contains an AsyncImage')
            return
    print('Button does not contain an AsyncImage')
```

And change the `kv`:

```
    on_press: app.moves(self)
```

to:

```
    on_press: app.moves(self, root)
```

Comment: How to check if any index of a list contains the id of the AsyncImage of the instance.children because I have changed asyncImage variable to be a list

Comment: Sounds like you need to post another question.